# Data bar length isn't correct for 0% and 100%

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel sheet for which I want to add a `DataBarRule`. Technically it works but in excel it doesn't look correct. The type of the data  bar is percent but for 0% the data bar doesn't disappear and for 100% it doesn't fill out the cell completely. For 50% it looks correct.

[image: Databar]

##### Code

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import DataBarRule


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("./test.xlsm", keep_vba=True)
ws = wb["Overview"]

rule = DataBarRule(
    start_type="percent",
    start_value=0,
    end_type="percent",
    end_value=100,
    color="000000",
    showValue=None,
    minLength=None,
    maxLength=None,
)

ws.conditional_formatting.add("A1:A3", rule)

wb.save("./test.xlsm")
```

##### Reproduction Steps

1. Create excel file called `test.xlsm`
2. Create excel sheet called `Overview`
3. Write following values into the cells `A1:A3`: `0`, `0.5`, `1` and set the number format to percent
4. Run code

Comment: Try setting `minLength=0` and `maxLength=100`. I assume that setting those to `None` is interpreted as `Auto` in Excel, which sometimes might not be the best option.

Comment: Earlier versions of Excel set minLength/maxLength to 10/90 which is what you see in your screen shot. This was changed in Excel 2010 or later release. If you add the bars manually in these versions it should be 0/100, I know this is the case for at least release 2013 and later.  The is no option to set minLength/maxLength manually in Excel (Libre Office includes the option but is usually disabled).

Comment: @eventHandler This fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @eventHandler already commented, the problem is that the two parameters for the length (`minLength` and `maxLength`) are set to `None`, which Excel interprets as `Auto`. In older versions of Excel, this means a length of `10` to `90` instead of `0` to `100`.

The solution for this is to manually set `minLength=0` and `maxLength=100`:

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import DataBarRule

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("./test.xlsm", keep_vba=True)
ws = wb["Overview"]

rule = DataBarRule(
    start_type="percent",
    start_value=0,
    end_type="percent",
    end_value=100,
    color="000000",
    showValue=None,
    minLength=0,        # manually set minLength
    maxLength=100,      # manually set maxLength
)
ws.conditional_formatting.add("A1:A3", rule)

wb.save("./test.xlsm")
```